# Import multiple lines of multiple HTML files, into cells (below each other) in one Excel file

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have multiple HTML files, with specific data that I like to see ordered in one Excel file.

The part I'm interested in of the HTML file are lines 99, 101, 102

```
   98       <div class="panel-body">
   99         V.O.F. Benerink<br>
   100 <address>
   101   huissinkweg 3-A<br>
   102   7522AK, Drente
   103 </address>
   104
   105 De heer M.N. Helthuis<br>
   106 <br>
   107
   108       </div>
   109     </div>
   110   </div>
```

And from 152 until 159:

```
   151           <dl class="dl-horizontal">
   152             <dt>Levensfase</dt>
   153             <dd>Nog te kwalificeren</dd>
   154             <dt>Bedrijfsgrootte</dt>
   155             <dd>Groot</dd>
   156             <dt>FTE</dt>
   157             <dd>2</dd>
   158             <dt>Cultuur</dt>
   159             <dd>Gww. grond weg water</dd>
   160           </dl>
```

I searched on multiple forums, and I found something on this website https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/342275-import-multiple-files-into-excel-3.html, but this didn't work for me. The topic is 9 years old, so I don't bother to ask there.

Who can provide some answers or code how to get these HTML lines of multiple HTML files into one sheet in Excel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Resources to help with this:

- [jQuery `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [ExcelPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/ExcelPlus/)

You'll want to do something along the lines of this (if you need additional help let me know):

1. Put a `span class="something"` around whatever you want in your spreadsheet (in this case, the lines you mentioned)
2. Load all those spans into a single html file using

   ```
   $('#some-container').load('a.html span.something')
   ```
3. Implement ExcelPlus using something like:

   ```
   var ep = new ExcelPlus(),
       content = [];

   $('span.something').each(function(i){
     content[0][i] = $(this).text();
   });

   ep.createFile("Book1").write({"content":content}).saveAs("demo.xlsx");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, there would be +1000 .html files where I have to add the `span` tag. But I can try something based on your answer.